# jsx Failed to compile Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Its difficult for me to understand the errors in this JSX code. It feels like I am applying the correct conventional rules for JSX but below I've posted the feedback that I've received from the console and it seems to stem from the first forEach method inside of the promise.

```
    class EventQueries extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
entertainer: null
}
}
render(){


return(

<div className = 'Immediate_Events'>
    <header className = 'ImmEventsTitle'>
        Upcoming Events
    </header>
    <div className = 'EventBlock'>
        {return this.props.queryEvent(this.props.query).then(() => this.props.queried_events.forEach(function(event){
        return (    <div>
            <span className = 'EventTitle'>JSON.parse(event["title"])</span>
            {this.props.artist_events ?
            this.props.artists_events.forEach((entertainer) => {
            return <span className = 'ArtistName'>
                <span onClick = {this.state.entertainer !== entertainer.name ? this.props.ParseEventsByArtist(entertainer.name, this.props.eventForecast).then(function(){this.setState({artist: entertainer.name})}) : null}>
                    entertainer.name
                </span>
            </span>}) :
            event.performers.forEach((entertainer) => { return <span className = 'ArtistName'>
                <span onClick = {this.state.entertainer !== entertainer.name ? this.props.ParseEventsByArtist(entertainer.name, this.props.eventForecast).then(function(){this.setState({artist: entertainer.name})}) : null}>
                    entertainer.name
                </span>
            </span>
            })
            }
            <span className = 'EventHappenstance'>JSON.parse(event["venue"]["name"])</span>
            <span className = 'EventAddress'>JSON.parse(event["venue"]["address"]), JSON.parse(event["venue"]["extended_address"])</span>
        </div>
        )
        }))
        }
    </div>

</div>
)
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
queried_events: state.eventOptions.queried_events
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {queryEvent})(EventQueries)
```

In the browser console, this is what I am getting in return for this particular file: EventQueries.js

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to split your code into smaller bits, it will be much more debuggable. For example the ternary operator is some 10 lines of code. The bare return statement seems out of place after `<div className = 'EventBlock'>`. Do you have a jsx syntax highlighter in you editor? It would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple mistake. I simply needed to add a return in front of queried_events in the mapStateToProps in order for the function to understand what the this.props.queried_events was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the return statement from here:

```
<div className = 'EventBlock'>
  {return
```

You're essentially nesting a `return` inside a `return`. It's not necessary there.